# how to fix 'parsing error: Unexpected token =>' in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am using firebase functions for stripe payment integration. This particular function used for register customer with stripe.

Node version 10.15.3 ,

npm version 6.9.0 ,

"ecmaVersion": 6 in .eslintrc.json

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.testkey)

exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user()

          .onCreate(async (user) => {
             const customer = await
             stripe.customers.create({email: user.email});
             await admin.firestore()
               .collection('stripe_customers')
               .doc(user.uid)
               .set({customer_id: customer.id});

           });
```

The code is same as the firebase platform provide on github example 
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/stripe/functions/index.js

> Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

and if I change the "ecmaVersion": 6 to "ecmaVersion": 8 in .eslintrc.json

```
then error is .onCreate(async (user) => {

                            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

I want to deploy function properly so that user can register on stripe and date store in firebase storage

Comment: I think there is no need of async just remove async from ur onCreate method exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  // ...
});

Comment: now it give Parsing error: Unexpected token admin

Comment: You get this error when you run the code or it's an eslint error?

Comment: I think code is run when function deploy properly and new user register to firebase authentication . At the time of user creation this code is run.      but the error gives these lines in terminal :  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.

Comment: @ray so it's clearly not liking async/await syntax. But: is this _node_ failing? Because I'm pretty sure node itself can run this just fine. Are you sure this isn't just your linter/transpiler being some older version that doesn't know async/await are real keywords?

Comment: `const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.testkey)` should end with a semicolon, no?

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you are running in your local machine node >= 8. For deployment, you should have in your package.json.

```
{
    //...
    "engines": {
        "node": "8"
    },
    //...  
}
```

For eslint, to enable parsing for async functions, you should include this in your config:

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2017
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're talking about an eslint error. I've been able to [reproduce](https://eslint.org/demo/#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) it in the eslint demo page using ecmaVersion 2015.

I just changed it to ecmaVersion 2017 (the version from when `async/await` was supported) and the error has gone away ([link](https://eslint.org/demo/#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)).

Also, verified the eslint config in the project you're talking about. It's ecmaVersion 2017: [link](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/62dfb26c06b067a84a1a428e9b967d51d0149a55/stripe/functions/.eslintrc.json#L4)

Comment: Issue resolved           I just run these two commands  1. npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save.  2.
npm install -g firebase-tools                                   I think it. update the Firebase Tools and it do not give error now

Comment: You didn't clarify whether it was an error from node or eslint. It would be helpful for someone coming to question in the future.

Comment: I think its not code error, actually before running these commands while deploy it show me Node.js 6 but after that it  show me Node.js 8 while deploy ,So I think that resolve my problem and also ESLint is inbuilt with firebase tools because it ask for it when we run firebase init ,so may it also update ESLint                                        Or           in my problem may be ESLint and node are not compatible I think so @Maaz Syed Adeeb

Answer (score 0):

I am new to React-native + firebase function. But with these lines of code, lint issue went out and I can now deploy firebase functions.

Old

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/firebase-schema.json",
  "react-native": {
    "crashlytics_auto_collection_enabled": true,
    "crashlytics_debug_enabled": true,
    "messaging_android_notification_channel_id": "high-priority",
    "messaging_ios_auto_register_for_remote_messages": true
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

New

```
{
  "$schema":"./node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/firebase-schema.json",
  "react-native": {
      "crashlytics_auto_collection_enabled": true,
      "crashlytics_debug_enabled": true,
      "messaging_android_notification_channel_id": "high-priority",
      "messaging_ios_auto_register_for_remote_messages":true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This solved my issue

```
{...
   "parserOptions": {
   "ecmaVersion": 8
}
```